# Powershell вызов функции из DLL

Tags: api, dll, powershell, dllimport

Есть DLL Api написанная на C++ от одного разработчика, я бы хотел понять как с помощью PowerShell подключить DLL и работать с ней.
Гуглил, но хороших ответов не нашел. 
Спасибо.

Comment: Везде полно примеров через `Add-Type` и кусок C# кода с `DllImport`. Чем он вам не подходит?

Comment: Платформа .NET, предоставляет довольно много способов вызова функций (в том числе и по их ординалам) из сторонних библиотек, которые также можно использовать и в PowerShell (если отбросить в сторону командлет _Add-Type_). За счет рефлексии и обобщенных делегатов можно вполне вызывать некоторые API функции сторонних библиотек без создания дополнительных сборок в домене приложений; можно реализовать лейер для того же _DllImport_, словом, все зависит от фантазии.